# How to fix "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree” for sql for execution?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have to sort this table of "Report's" on data within a nested table. I.e. each Report item has a number of Net's associated with it and each Net has a status attribute that I need to sort the list of Reports on. Here is an example of what I've been able to get so far, however I am having trouble being able to write this in a way that will be acceptable for IOrderedQueryable because I need this to still be translated into SQL and executed through that rather than where I am writing the code:

```
var orderedReports = reports.OrderBy((r) =>
{
    switch (r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("New")) ? "New" :
            r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("Updated")) ? "Updated" :
            r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("Ignored")) ? "Ignored" : "None" )
    {
        case "New": return 1;
        case "Updated": return 2;
        case "Ignored": return 3;
        case "None": return 4;
        default: return 5;
    }
}).ThenBy(r => r.ReportID);
```

I realize that many reports can have similar or even matching number of statuses so after the initial sort, I then sort by the ID of that report. I basically want all the reports that have at least one "New" status first, then the others to follow as described above. I also want to reiterate that I need to make sure this stays in IOrderedQueryable because this needs to be executed in SQL when making the query to the database.

Comment: It can be reduced to just `r => r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("New")) ? 1 : r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("Updated")) ? 2 :
r.Nets.Any(n => n.Status.Contains("Ignored")) ? 3 : 4` for starters.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. I've been working off a few different methods and have been mashing things together, it gets lost in translation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the switch statement has no SQL equivelant and it's expecting to run this in Linq to Objects.

It appears that a conditional operator has a direct conversion:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38264/How-to-Create-T-SQL-CASE-Statements-With-LINQ-To-S

I highly recommend testing in LinqPad because it can produce the SQL equivalents to help you with debugging.